# keep notification on lock screen after unlock it

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, lockscreen, unlock

Am newbie in IOS. I want to create an app in which unread reminder notification OR any local Notification and should not remove from lock screen of iphone. When i slide to unlock and lock it again then my notification remove from lock screen.
i Attached three screenshots in which notification is display and after that it removes. See reference Image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa2jV.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCAX2.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep notification on lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174001/keep-notification-on-lock-screen)